# Read phone state broadcast is not getting called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I am trying to listen phone state. I have registered receiver in my manifest file. But the receiver is not getting called.
I wanted to listen to phone state and start service once I receive Broadcast.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.networkmonitor" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectvityMonitor" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!--<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".NetWorkMonitorActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my Receiver

```
package com.example.networkmonitor;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ConnectvityMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String state="";



            Log.d("BroadCast Fired","BroadCast Fired");

            Toast.makeText(context,"BroadCast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



}
```

Comment: I am testing it on nexus 4.

Comment: Are you calling the broadcast receiver in a service/

Comment: Please look at the manifest. I have registered broadcast receiver for it. I want that to be triggered when Phone State gets changed. @Ranjith

Comment: If you dont call it a service the broadcast will not be active to listen to the phone state. If you are not calling the broadcast receiver in a service then you have to keep the app open to listen to the phone state. Call the broadcastreceiver in a service.

Comment: Ok Consider scenario where my app is closed and i want to add listen whenever my Network gone. Or Data connection close. How does it triggers service for such event. @Ranjith

Comment: When you open your app start a service, maybe a button to start the service. In the service register the receiver(ConnectivityManager). Now even the app is closed the service will be running in background and listening to phones state.